# Restricting deletion permissions in Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a node web app where I use Firebase for data storage, and I was wondering if there was a way from the Firebase console to add Rules to only allow creation and viewing of data on a certain database.

For example, in my app, I want users to be able to create a message and view messages, however I don't want them to ever be able to delete them.

**Is there a way to restrict deletion of documents in Firestore rules?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can break down `write` into more *granular operations*, as stated [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations):

> A read rule can be broken into get and list, while a **write** rule can be broken into **create**, **update**, and **delete**:

An example of your particular case:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /messages/{messageId} {
      allow read, create, update: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the response! Following up on that, is there a way in the rules to restrict these operations to only take place on a certain URL/domain. So if my app is hosted at example.com, can I write something in that rule to only allow requests from example.com?

Comment: Not really, you'll have to get creative, maybe storing the domain a user is bound to in the database then compare to that, or create a custom auth token, to which you have access to in the rules.